# reinterpret<char**> from new char[]

Tags: c++

So I saw this piece of code that's confusing me:

```
class DynamicBuffer
{
    private:
    
        char* _buf = nullptr; 
   
    public:
        void Resize(size_t size)
        {
            char* resizeBuf = new char[size];
            char **ptr = reinterpret_cast<char**>(resizeBuf);
            *ptr = _buf;
            _buf = resizeBuf;
        }
}
```

I'm hung up on:

```
char **ptr = reinterpret_cast<char**>(resizeBuf);
*ptr = _buf;
```

Am I right in thinking the author was trying to make the first sizeof(char) bytes to point the older buffer?
How is this not undefined behavior?

Why not just do this:

```
char** resizeBuf = new char*[size];
```

Comment: Where did you see that code? Where does it come from? Have you tried contacting the authors or maintainers to ask them?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Im unable to contact the author

Comment: @273K that was my C# creeping in. fixed

Comment: It is storing the old pointer at the beginning of the new allocation. Is that pointer maybe used later, e.g. to chain allocations? (It is probably UB, but only for a small technicality.)

Comment: It would also be interesting to see how this `DynamicBuffer` class is used, and how it uses its `_buf` member, and how and when and where the `Resize` function is called.

Comment: @user17732522 I believe so. Almost like a linked list. the problem is in my mini example I can't access  the buffer in _buf[0]. I've tried `*reinterpret_cast<char*>(_buf)` but it doesn't work

Comment: @LewsTherin If it is storing the pointer at the beginning you get the pointer with `*reinterpret_cast<char**>(_buf)`, and the first proper element by offsetting the index: `_buf[sizeof(char*)]`. (Technically `std::launder` is required after the `reinterpret_cast` to get the pointer.)

Comment: The "link" in the data is stored using `sizeof(char*)` bytes. You have to do the exact same `reinterpret_cast<char**>` as is being done here to follow the link.

Comment: @user17732522 sorry Im a bit lost. How does `_buf[sizeof(char*)]` this work exactly? Assuming the size is 1 byte won't access the second element in buf?

Comment: @LewsTherin I am making some assumptions of course since the code you have shown is limited, so I am assuming that the intention is to store a pointer for the "linked-list" at the beginning of `_buf` taking up the first `sizeof(char*)` bytes and then the rest of the allocation is the "data" of the list node which is basically an array `char[size-sizeof(char*)]`. The `i`th element of the latter array is `_buf[sizeof(char*)+i]` because it is placed at a `sizeof(char*)` bytes offset in the allocated array.

Comment: Regarding the actual question at the end of your post: because it's not equivalent to what is being done. `new char*[size]` allocates space for `size` new *pointers*. That's not what the authors code does, so that's "why not".

Comment: @user17732522 yeah I think you've made it clear. thanks!

Comment: @WhozCraig that's true

Comment: @user17732522 if you want to put a detailed answer Im happy to accept it. Or I could delete this question

Comment: @LewsTherin I don't have time to write it out right now, but I think an answer could also explain why this method is used and where there is technically UB. That might make for a good answer, I think.

Comment: @user17732522 sure go for it, thanks !

Comment: you can basically replace those two lines with just `memcpy((void*)resizeBuf, (void*)&buf, sizeof(buf));` maybe they tought memcpy was uglier, but I think it makes the intend a lot clearer

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a roundabout version of basically writing:

```
void Resize(size_t size)
{
    assert(size >= sizeof(char*));
    char* resizeBuf = new char[size];
    memcpy((void*)resizeBuf, (void*)&_buf, sizeof(_buf));
    _buf = resizeBuf;
}
```

Or using placement new to do essentially the same thing.

```
void Resize(size_t size)
{
    assert(size >= sizeof(char*));
    char* resizeBuf = new char[size];
    char** firstPointer = new(resizeBuf) char*;
    *firstPointer = _buf;
    _buf = resizeBuf;
}
```

I think the memcpy version happens to be well-defined because the default alignment for memory allocated with new `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` should accomodate pointers.

Memcpy is also allowed to [implicitly create](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Object_creation) new objects, which just a regular assignment is not allowed to do without the prior placement new.

Comment: Or just `new(resizeBuf) char*(_buf)` for the placement-new version.

Comment: Implicit object creation should also happen with `new char[size]`, however the pointer returned by `new` isn't pointing to the implicitly-created `char*`, so technically the original version is probably UB for using a wrong pointer value.

Comment: true, it's more precise to say "implicit object creation of the right type", since the objects created inside the array are of type `char` and not `char*`

Comment: `new char[size]` also implicitly creates objects of other implicit-lifetime types as needed, which would be nested inside the `char[size]` array (except that there is [a wording defect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2489)). However the pointer returned by `new char[size]` is always to the first `char` object, not the `char*` object, which means technically `std::launder` would probably be required (all of this assuming C++17 or later). Although these details seem a bit unclear to me as well.

Comment: How is the first code section the same as the second bit? Looks like they are doing different stuff

Comment: @user17732522 "new char[size] also implicitly creates objects of other implicit-lifetime types as needed, which would be nested inside the char[size] array " where can I read about this?

Comment: @LewsTherin [P0593](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html) is the proposal which introduced it. There are some examples in it. If you want to learn about the object model in general, maybe start at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object.

Comment: @LewsTherin Regarding the two examples in the answer: The second example creates a new `char*` object at the beginning of the allocation explicitly and then sets its value via assignment. The first version doesn't explicitly create or set the value, but instead copies the object representation of the pointer into the front of the allocation, which together with implicit object creation has the exact same effect.

Comment: @LewsTherin if you need to see them being the exact same, you can look at the code they generate https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z6GzhK1dc . It's the exact same instruction for instruction: https://i.imgur.com/HDrqHg2.png

Comment: @PeterT thanks I see it now

Comment: @PeterT you were actually passing `&_buf` which I failed to see. makes sense now